# how do i append a list of ids to a http webrequest in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a class that sends a widget request. During the first run the widget-id that i append to the URL of the request should be null. then during the next runs the id should be fetched from an isolatedstorage(widgetIDlist). this isolated storage contains the list of ids of all the widgets that i have recieved in the first run. Now, how do i append this list to my request? the code is

```
Widget_Buffer.Append("&_widgetId=").Append(CacheManager.getInstance().getWidgetIDList());
```

since getwidgetlist takes a string argument i need to pass a string in the above code and am confused as to what i should pass to obtain the right data.

```
 public string[] getWidgetIDList(string key)
    {
       if (key == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        try
        {
            Value = WidgetList[key];
            WidgetID = Value.ToString();

            if (WidgetID != null)
            {

                return WidgetIDsList;
            }
        }
     }
```

I have a class wr am parsing the file that contains the widget id and storing all the info in it..the code goes like this..

```
public string getId()
    {

        CacheManager.getInstance().setWidgetIDList(id,id);
        return id;
    }

  public void setWidgetIDList(string key,string value)
    {
        try
        {
            WidgetList.Add(key, value);
            WidgetList.Save();
        }
      }
```

how do i append the list of widget-id list?? to the first line of code that i have put here??
am i doing the other things correctly???

Comment: If it's your service you send request to, then just make contract that all ids are separated by e.g. "|". So you will send such request "&_widgetId=1|2|3".

Comment: thr are about 20 ids, i dunno the ids they are just stored when they are recieved.. how do i append them to the widgetid parameter??? and they should be seperated by coma(,).

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem, is this that you want know how to send a array of WidgetID in Request URL??

Comment: If so my idea is you to check the Web request URL encoding, and accordingly modify, request URl building code. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i did the following changes in the getwidgetlist method...n now am able to append all the ids :)

```
 StringBuilder idList = new StringBuilder();
        bool flag = false;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, WidgetBean> key in beanList)
        {
            WidgetBean bean = key.Value;
            if (!flag)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                idList.Append(bean.getId()).Append(',');
            }
          }
```